# Access Data on click event from table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, post

i have table "login" and listing the data from mysql using php into table in html.

```
<table class="table">
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Sl.NO</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                                <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
                                <th scope="col">Join Date</th>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                if($req_result->num_rows > 0)
                                    {
                                        while($req_row = $req_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            $i+=1;
                                            $reqmail = $req_row['username'];
                                            $reqmobile = $req_row['id'];
                                            $reqname = $req_row['name'];
                                            $join_date = $req_row['join_date'];

                                            ?>

                                            <tr>
                                              <th scope="row"><?php echo $i ;?></th>
                                              <td><?php echo $reqname ;?></td>
                                              <td><?php echo $reqmail ;?></td>
                                              <td><?php echo $reqmobile ;?></td>
                                              <td><?php echo $join_date ; ?></td>
                                              <td><button type="submit" value="'.$reqmobile.'" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm">Approve</button></td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>

                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

i want to acccess that button value on click, and process another queries.the tbale "login" has multiple datas. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this. If something comes up let me know.Cheers

```
//catch html button with js assigned to variable button
let button = document.querySelector('.btn btn-primary');

//listen for the click
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   button.value;
});
// console log the the value of button
console.log(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are multiple rows in the table and thus multiple buttons in the generated HTML you need to use a method that will capture a reference to all elements to which an event listener is to be assign - unless you opt to use `event delegation` but in this instance there is no need to do so. To capture a reference to the buttons `document.querySelectorAll` seems apropriate in vanilla javascript - and to facilitate the use of `forEach` in some browsers the `nodelist` that `document.querySelectorAll` is converted to an array.

Each button is assigned an anonymous ( in this case anyway ) function to process `click` events - the value of `this` within the anonymous function refers to the button which allows easy access to any of it's attributes - here only `value` is of interest

```
let col=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'td > input[type="submit"]' ) );
    col.forEach( input =>{
        input.addEventListener('click',function(event){
            alert( 'Value: '+this.value );
        });
    });
```